# Confusing Behavior with Array Initialization -- Processing (Java)

Tags: java, processing

I'm encountering some confusing behavior when trying to create an array of certain length.  The length is obtained by a file read in the function getTermNums.  When I try to create an array of this size, my code runs in a strange order, my i values are skewed, and the code generally doesn't run as intended.  When I instead create an array of a set integer amount, the code runs as intended without error.

```java
   double[] terms;

    int numTerms = getNumTerms(lines[0]);
    terms = new double[numTerms];

    int i = 1;

    for (i = 1; i<terms.length; i++){
      //terms[i] = calculateTerm(T, lines[i]);

    }
```

the above code runs incorrectly.

```java
    double[] terms;

    int numTerms = getNumTerms(lines[0]);

    int myNum = 200;
    terms = new double[myNum];

    int i = 1;

    for (i = 1; i<terms.length; i++){
      //terms[i] = calculateTerm(T, lines[i]);
```

the above code runs correctly

```java
int getNumTerms(String line){

    int i = 60;
    int j = 0;
    char[] word;
    word = new char[4];
    int numTerms;
    int numTermLen = 0;


    while(new String(word).compareTo("TERM") != 0){
      for (j=0; j<4; j++){

        word[j] = line.charAt(i + j);
      }
      i++;
    }
    j = i - 3;

    while( new Character(line.charAt(j)).equals(' ') == false){

      numTermLen++;
      j--;
    }

    j++;
    println("i in here: ", i);
    numTerms = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(j, j + numTermLen));
    return numTerms;
  }
```

this is the function that I'm calling to read the numterms for the size of the array in the first example that doesn't work correctly.

When I use the function call to set the size of array terms[], i starts at some value like 380, and the iteration through array lines[] begins somewhere in the middle of the array. 
When I use the integer myNum to set the size of array terms[], i starts at 1, and the iteration through array lines[] begins at the first line, as intended.

Any explanation is appreciated! I'm new to coding in java and am confused by the source of this error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a sample of the text you're parsing ? there might be a problem with how you parse the `numTerms` integer value.

Comment: Have you used debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the text it's tiresome to deduct where in your `getNumTerms` the error occurs.

You can make use of [String's indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to find the index of "TERM" and [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to extract the String containing the integer value.

As far as I understand the ideal string would have "TERM" followed by an integer then a space character. If these items are found and the [value fits within 32 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you should be able to use something like this:

```
String line = "LINE START TERM-1238847 LINE END";

int getTerm(String line){
  int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  final String SEARCH_TOKEN = "TERM";
  // look for TERM token and remember index
  int termIndex = line.indexOf(SEARCH_TOKEN);
  // handle not found
  if(termIndex < 0){
    System.err.println("error: " + SEARCH_TOKEN + " not found in line");
    return result;
  }
  // move index by the size of the token
  termIndex += SEARCH_TOKEN.length();
  int spaceIndex = line.indexOf(' ',termIndex);
  if(spaceIndex < 0){
    System.err.println("error: no SPACE found after " + SEARCH_TOKEN);
    return result;
  }
  // chop string extracing between token end and first space encountered
  String intString = line.substring(termIndex,spaceIndex);
  // try to parse int handling error
  try{
    result = Integer.parseInt(intString);
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("error parsing integer from string " + intString);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return result;
}


System.out.println("parsed integer: " + getTerm(line));
```